# ¿Como saber con JavaScript hacia que direccion se hace scroll?

Tags: javascript

¿Como se hacia que direccion se hace scroll en la pagina?. Quiero que cuando se haga scroll hacia abajo se haga una accion y otra accion al hacer scroll hacia arriba.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo almacenando el anterior valor de scrollTop y comparándolo con su valor actual, todo esto con el evento scroll del documento:

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
   var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
     console.log('para abajo');
   } else {
     console.log('para arriba');
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
}, false);
```

```css
.test {
  height: 1500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  </div>
```

Esta respuesta se basó en una [existente en SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223341/javascript-detecting-scroll-direction).